Encrypt sql password in Kafka connect property file
How do I encrypt password in Kafka connect properties file
My property file looks like below
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
connection.url = jdbc:sqlserver://<connection string>
connection.user = <SQL user id>
connection.password = <Plain text password>
mode=incrementing 
name=<Topic name>
schema.partern=dbo
query = <select from view query>
table.types = VIEW
incrementing.column.name=Application_Identity

How do I avoid using plain text password to avoid security violation?
Im using Kafka in Linux server and Database as SqL server.

dont use properties file for password, use environment var, call parameter, user prompt, or other volatile method to specify it

@PerdiEstaquel Have you configured kafka connect before? Do you have examples of each of those?

see: Kafka Connect, JDBC connector password in clear text. How to avoid? ?


Connect standalone is not recommended. Use distributed mode, which uses JSON config
Depends on your needs, but in general, Debezium is better for CDC capture from a database
Kafka Connect supports Configuration Externalization, for worker properties. Depending on what version of Connect you're using, environment variables would be easiest.

